# Making sense of rational powers of the $j$-invariant

Tags: complex-analysis, modular-forms, branch-cuts

I have seen in the literature solutions to modular differential equations which include rational powers of the $j$-invariant (also called $j$-function), e.g., $j(\tau)^{1/p}$ for some $p \in \mathbb Z \backslash\{0\}$.

I am curious how this is defined, because not only is there an issue of which branch to choose, a priori I would think monodromy may enter the picture too, and so I would question whether $j(\tau)^{1/p}$ is single-valued for a particular $p$.

Is there any source that discusses this or could someone provide clarification? It seems to pop up often without discussion so I presume there might be some conventions I'm unaware of.

Comment: It won't cause problems if you specify $j(i)^{1/p}=1728^{1/p}$ and ensure $j(\tau)$ does not hit zero in the discussion.

Comment: @TravorLZH thank you. Can you just elaborate as to why specifying the value at $i$ is sufficient?

Comment: The reason is the same for complex logarithm. Specify $\log(z)=0$ at $z=1$ and ensure $z$ does not hit zero in the calculations.